# ASP.NET web.config authorization settings ignored

Tags: asp.net, web-config, forms-authentication, authorization

I was searching for some solution but can't find one.  There is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1306856/authorization-settings-for-a-folder-in-asp-net) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/691533/asp-net-web-config-authorization-settings-ignored) ones but can't found and answer there. Im developing an asp.net application on **ASP.NET development server**.  I have the following web.config in my root asp.net folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>  
<configuration>  
  <system.web>  
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />  
    <authentication mode="Forms">  
      <forms name="4df5d465h"  
          loginUrl="~/login.aspx"  
          protection="All"  
          timeout="30" path="/" />  
    </authentication>  
    <authorization>  
      <deny users="?"/>  
    </authorization>  
  </system.web>  
</configuration>
```

My image folder is together my main web.config at root asp.net application folder.
***Inside the image folder*** I put the following web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>  
<configuration>  
  <system.web>  
    <authorization>  
      <allow roles="*"/>  
      <allow users="*"/>  
    </authorization>  
  </system.web>  
</configuration>
```

I put role attribute after to see if its work.
I wrote the main web.config in this way too:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>  
<configuration>
  <system.web>  
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />  
    <authentication mode="Forms">  
      <forms name="3D45C7D8B0B0C"  
          loginUrl="~/login.aspx"  
          protection="All"  
          timeout="30" path="/" />  
    </authentication>  
    <authorization>  
      <deny users="?"/>  
    </authorization>  
  </system.web>  

  <location path="~/image">  
    <system.web>  
      <authorization>  
        <allow users="*"/>  
      </authorization>  
    </system.web>  
  </location>  
</configuration>
```

**But the login page never can load the images**

In design mode, inside visual studio editor, the image load in login.aspx page then image tag must be ok.

What I'm doing wrong??  Thanks a lot.

@nico, thanks a lot for format my question. No im not rewriting nothing. Its most simple and default asp.net application possible. Its default template asp.net application with an link on Default.aspx and a simple login.aspx page, its a test project, the login form works but the image doesn't load.

@Chris_Lively, yes there is a web.config in image folder, its web.config with <'allow roles='*'>, i checked, the folder is named image\ , the src of image tag point to image\ its getting me crazy

Comment: Do you have a .config file in your image directory?  Also, have you confirmed that the directory is named "image" as opposed to "images"?

Comment: Try using a single web.config file as you have in the last example but move the location section above the system.web section.

Comment: have you tried adding 
  <location path="~/login.aspx">, allowing all users?

Answer (score 1):

Your config file contains error - 'roles'-tag cannot use asterisk, you should define specific role name ([allow element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acsd09b0.aspx)) or dont use it at all.

You'll see error message 'Parser Error Message: Authorization rule names cannot contain the '*' character' in [fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/fiddler2/).

I think it was reason of your problem.